# How to get context (route name) an app is in for styling purposes?

Tags: ember.js

Having very simple routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', {path: '/'}, function() {
    this.resource('user', {path: '/user/:user_id'});
  });
});
```

and the following templates:

```
# application
.container= outlet

# users
.left
  ul.users-list= each controller
    li= link-to 'user' this
      = fullName
.main
  = outlet

# users/index
p please select user from the list
```

is it possible to get current app state? For example it'd be useful to know that `usersIndexRoute` is active (kind of blank state) to style `.main` differently.
Preferably I'd like to have this state in application view, e.g binding in `.container`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `currentPath` of `ApplicationController` to get the current route path and bind it to the class of `container`:

#### application_view.js

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  classForPath: (function() {
    var currentPath = this.get('controller.currentPath') || '';
    currentPath = Ember.String.decamelize(currentPath);
    currentPath = currentPath.split('.').join('-');
    return currentPath;
  }).property('controller.currentPath')
});
```

#### application.handlebars

```
<div {{bindAttr class=":container view.classForPath"}}>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for! We can go even further and set context directly on the body provided that app is only made of Ember (not a part of the page).

Answer (score 4):

Riffing off of [@Panagiotis Panagi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359104/panagiotis-panagi) answer, you can simply bind your `classForPath` property to your application view as follows:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['app'], // Static classes here.
  classNameBindings: ['classForPath'], // Your dynamic path here.
  classForPath: function() {
    var currentPath = this.get('controller.currentPath') || '';
    currentPath = Ember.String.decamelize(currentPath);

    // Note we prefix with a string 'current-path-' in case the route is 
    // an integer e.g., 404. CSS classes cannot start with numbers.
    currentPath = 'current-path-' + currentPath.split('.').join('-');
    return currentPath;
  }.property('controller.currentPath')
});
```